# Codeigniter popup validation with javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>test/loadsql"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                    <input type="file" required aria-required="true" id="upload" name="upload"/>
                    <input type="button" onclick="validate()"  class="btn btn-success " value= "Upload">
                    </form>

function validate()
{
    job=confirm("Are you sure to upload?");
    if(job!=true)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

if its true i want to load the form action test/loadsql

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the button type `submit` instead of `button`  And declare the click function `return` is important to returning the function

**Updated answer validate the input**

```js
function validate()
{
  var input =document.getElementById('upload').value;
   if(input){
      var  job=confirm("Are you sure to upload?");
    if(job!=true)
    {
      console.log('not allow')
        return false;
    }
  else{
    console.log("pass")
      return true;
    }
    }
  else{
     alert('Please choose some file')
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>test/loadsql"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                    <input type="file" required aria-required="true" id="upload" name="upload"/>
                    <input type="submit" onclick="return validate()"  class="btn btn-success " value= "Upload">
                    </form>
```

Comment: hi ALL, As i have given <input type="file" required aria-required="true" when i click upload button it is asking twice "Are you sure you want to upload". can you please help on this

Comment: could you tell if you need a two time's confirm ?

Comment: First when i click upload it should alert ("no file chosen"). once the file is uploaded and then click upload, it should ask for the message" Are you sure you want to upload" Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `onsubmit()` event on form as below..

View:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('test/loadsql');?>"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="validate();"> 

<input type="file" required aria-required="true" id="upload" name="upload"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value= "Upload">

 </form>
```

Javascript

```
function validate()
{
    if(window.confirm("Are you sure to upload?"))
    {
        return true;
    }
  else{
      return false;
    }
}
```